# how to accept multiple answers in 1 variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

im trying to get users to input different strings for Fav_show that can trigger the correct show. i've tried `Fav_show = ("game of thrones", "GOT")` and `Fav_show = ("game of thrones" or "GOT")` but my script makes `guess != Fav_show` if i enter game of thrones/GOT, how would I got about making `guess = Fav_show` for multiple answers.

```
Fav_show = ("game of thrones")
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 0
guess_a_show = False

if raw_input == "whats your favourite tv show":
    guess_a_show = input("you have to take a guess, okay? ")
    if guess_a_show == "okay":
        print("take a guess, you have 5 chances ")
        while guess != Fav_show and guess_count < 1:
```

Sorry I'm new to python, and I've tried looking around for about 30-45 mins, but maybe I'm looking at the wrong places

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list with possible answers of the user:

got_list = ['got', 'Game of Thrones', 'GOT']

Then:

```
while guess not in got_list and guess_cout < 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through the whole list manually and doing the comparison with  `for x in list...` you could also use the `in` operator:

`if x in list return True` or even better just return the `in` comparison straight up `return x in list`, just keep in mind that for string comparison letter casing does come into play and you should either use `'string'.upper()'` or `'string'.lower()`.